# unable to deserialize all elements of this xml

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, deserialization

Few elements of this XML does not deserialize and but it does not throw any errors either.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TrialMWordsRecord xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <MyList>
    <MWords>
      <Id>0</Id>
      <Name>ListMWords1</Name>
      <Type>LIST</Type>
      <MyOutput>true</MyOutput>
      <WordsElements>
        <Words>
          <Name>ListMWords1</Name>
          <Value>Apple</Value>
          <Type>STRING</Type>
        </Words>
        <Words>
          <Name>ListMWords1</Name>
          <Value>Mango</Value>
          <Type>STRING</Type>
        </Words>
        <Words>
          <Name>ListMWords1</Name>
          <Value>Chickoo</Value>
          <Type>STRING</Type>
        </Words>
      </WordsElements>
    </MWords>
    <MWords>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <Type>RANDOM</Type>
      <MyOutput>true</MyOutput>
      <WordsElements>
        <Name>Limit</Name>
        <Value>3,8</Value>
        <Type>NUMERIC</Type>
      </WordsElements>
    </MWords>
  </TrialMWordsList>
</MyListRecord>
```

Below are my classes:

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlRootAttribute("MyListRecord")]
public class MyList
{

    [XmlArray("MyList")]
    public List<MWords> MWords
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public static MyList Deserialize()
    {
        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyList));
        TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + "\\MyList.xml");

        MyList resultList = (MyList)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);

        textReader.Close();

        return resultList;
    }       
}

[Serializable()]
public class MWords
{

    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public MWordsType Type
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool MyOutput
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Requirement
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [XmlArrayItem("WordsElements")]
    public List<Words> WordList
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public static MWords Deserialize()
    {
        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MWords));
        TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + "\\MWords.xml");
        MWords mwords = (MWords)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
        textReader.Close();
        return mwords;
    }
}

public class Words
{
    public string Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public TYPE Type
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Now when I deserialize this XML, if **Type is LiST**, the WordList gets updated, e.g. here count for WordList will be 3 but if **Type is RANDOM**, WordList is 0 which should actually be 1 and not 0.
Really don't know what could be the reason.

Comment: does it give any exception ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your XML. Look at what it's like for your working case:

```
<WordsElements>
  <Words>
    <Name>ListMWords1</Name>
    <Value>Apple</Value>
    <Type>STRING</Type>
  </Words>
  <Words>
    ...
  </Words>
  <Words>
    ...
  </Words>
</WordsElements>
```

Now compare that with your broken case:

```
<WordsElements>
  <Name>Limit</Name>
  <Value>3,8</Value>
  <Type>NUMERIC</Type>
</WordsElements>
```

You've got no `Words` element in there - it should be:

```
<WordsElements>
  <Words>
    <Name>Limit</Name>
    <Value>3,8</Value>
    <Type>NUMERIC</Type>
  </Words>
</WordsElements>
```

If you can't change the XML, you *may* need to deserialize it by hand - which probably wouldn't be too hard.

As an aside, you might want to look into writing your automatically implemented properties on one line - it's a *lot* more compact to write

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

than

```
public string Name
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

... and it's no harder to read, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of element `WordsElements` for type **RANDOM** does not wrap in `<Words></Words>`:

```
<MWords>
  <Id>1</Id>
  <Type>RANDOM</Type>
  <MyOutput>true</MyOutput>
  <WordsElements>
    <Words>
      <Name>Limit</Name>
      <Value>3,8</Value>
      <Type>NUMERIC</Type>
    </Words>
  </WordsElements>
</MWords>
```